# How to generate a next series number and compare first one in php?

Tags: php

code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $number = 1000;
    $number++;
    $unique = strval($number);
    $product_id = "LTC_".$unique;
    $query = "insert into stock(`product_id`)values('".$product_id."')";
    //echo $query;

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($result==true)
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Record Save Successfully</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Unable to Save Please Try Again !!!</div>";
    }
}
```

In this code I have a variable i.e. `$product_id`. Now what am I doing here I am insert `product_id` value in a table suppose first value of `product_id` is `1001` next will be `1002`. Now I want to generate a new number in a series way and If I delete any `product_id` it will never ever repeat again. So, How can I do this ?

Comment: You mention "a table". Can you share the code related to the database, saving and reading?

Comment: I have edit my code please look at once @jcjr

Comment: Use GUID, instead of int for PK :) that way if you delete a product, the chance of repeating the GUID is minimalist

Comment: Try setting your DB table specified column to unique & auto increment. No need to insert value using query for a PK field. It will be always Unique & always be incrementing.

Comment: Is it possible to do through code that I have mention above because if I do specified column to unique it throw error of duplicate entry and it may be possible that I have duplicate date in my table @Sinto

Comment: ok, then it can be done by codes.

Comment: How, that would I am asking @Sinto

Comment: is there any chance to solve this problem @Sinto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"select max(product_id) as product_id from stock");
$fet = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$ides = $fet['product_id'];
$number = 1000;
$number++;
$unique = strval($number);
if($unique==$ides || $unique!=$ides)
{
    $new_id = ++$ides;
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $product_id = $new_id;
    //your custom code here
}
```

Comment: Thanx @sam orten

Answer (score 0):

Store the `$unique` number in a table, then always read it from database and then increment it, make the new `$product_id` then store the new value of `$unique` to the table.

Answer (score -1):

Try simply using auto-increment feature, without applying any unique constraint.